# My swap function which takes in pointer address does not swap the pointer. Why is that?

Tags: c

Current Outcome is:
After swapping
The first word you entered is **temp1**
The second word you entered is **temp2**

Expected Outcome should be:
After swapping
The first word you entered is **temp2** <<Expecting different results
The second word you entered is **temp1** <<Expecting different results

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    void swap1(char *pword1, char *pword2) {

        printf("word1 is %p\n",pword1);
        printf("word2 is %p\n",pword2);

        char temp[50] = "\0";
        char *ptemp = temp;
        ptemp = pword1;
        pword1 = pword2;
        pword2 = ptemp;

        printf("word1 is %p\n",pword1);
        printf("word2 is %p\n",pword2);

        return;
    }

    char word1[50];
    char word2[50];

    printf("Before swapping\n");
    printf("Enter the first word\n");
    scanf("%s",word1);
    printf("The first word you entered is %s\n",word1);
    char *pword1 = word1;

    printf("Enter the second word\n");
    scanf("%s",word2);
    printf("The second word you entered is %s\n",word2);
    char *pword2 = word2;

    swap1(pword1,pword2);

    printf("\nAfter swapping\n");
    printf("The first word you entered is %s\n",pword1);
    printf("The second word you entered is %s\n",pword2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your swap of the pointers inside the function does not affect the pointers outside. You need to pass `char**` for that. Also `temp` is not really needed.

Comment: That code shouldn't build to begin with. C doesn't allow nested functions (functions defined inside other functions).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think some compilers (GCC?) allow nested functions as an extension.

Comment: As for your problem, remember that in C arguments are passed *by value*, which of course includes pointers. All you do is assign to local variables, only changing the values of the local variables.

Comment: @AdrianMole Unfortunately yes.

Comment: When learning C, use the help you get you can get from the compiler: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic` - when you're comfortable with the language, you'll probably continue to use those flags just to make the compiler catch mistakes that even pros do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Re “C doesn't allow nested functions”: It is well known that the C standard **allows** many extensions. It explicitly states C implementations may accept programs whose behavior the standard does not specify. This is not primarily to allow compilers to be lax; it is to allow extensions to the language. That is a deliberate feature of the C standard. Stating that only the base features of the standard are “allowed” is a misrepresentation of the standard.

Comment: In order to solve this, you first need to make up your mind regarding if you should swap the pointers or the data they point at. Either could be a sensible implementation, depending on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You need one more level of indirection, but see my notes below.

Let's strip this down a bit - if you want a function to swap two values of any *non-array* type `T`, you must pass pointers to them:

```
void swap( T *a, T *b )
{
  T tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

int main( void )
{
  T x = some_T_value;
  T y = some_other_T_value;

  swap( &x, &y );
}
```

We have

```
 a == &x  // T * == T *
 b == &y  // T * == T *

*a ==  x  // T   == T
*b ==  y  // T   == T
```

Now let's replace `T` with the type `P *`:

```
void swap( P **a, P **b ) // T *a == P * *a == P **a
{
  P *tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

int main( void )
{
  P *x = some_Pstar_value;
  P *y = some_other_Pstar_value;

  swap( &x, &y );
}
```

Our relationships are still the same:

```
 a == &x  // P ** == P **
 b == &y  // P ** == P **

*a ==  x  // P *  == P *
*b ==  y  // P *  == P *
```

All the semantics are exactly the same - `a` and `b` are always one more level of indirection than `x` and `y`, `tmp` is always the same level of indirection as `x` and `y`, you always pass `&x` and `&y` - the only difference is the type.  Just to drive the point home, we'll go one more level and replace `P` with `R *`:

```
void swap( R ***a, R ***b ) 
{
  R **tmp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = tmp;
}

int main( void )
{
  R **x = some_Rstarstar_value;
  R **y = some_other_Rstarstar_value;

  swap( &x, &y );
}
```

NOTE - If you want to swap the contents of *arrays*, rather than pointers to arrays, you'll have to do something different:

```
void swapArr( T *a, T *b, size_t bytes )
{
  T tmp[size];
  memcpy( tmp, a, size );
  memcpy( a, b, size );
  memcpy( b, tmp, size );
}

int main( void )
{
  T a[N] = { ... };
  T b[N] = { ... };

  swap( a, b, sizeof a ); // no & operator
}
```